# Proving inversion lemma for subtyping, termination checking, `subst`

Tags: agda

I'm trying to prove the (first part of the) subtyping lemma from *Types and Programming Languages*.  Here's what I have so far:

```
data Type : Set where
  _=>_ : Type → Type → Type
  Top : Type

data _<:_ : Type → Type → Set where
  s-refl : {S : Type} → S <: S
  s-trans : {S T U : Type} → S <: U → U <: T → S <: T
  s-top : {S : Type} → S <: Top
  s-arrow : {S₁ S₂ T₁ T₂ : Type} → T₁ <: S₁ → S₂ <: T₂ → S₁ => S₂ <: T₁ => T₂

lemma-inversion₁ : {S T₁ T₂ : Type}                                                                                                                                 
  → S <: T₁ => T₂                                                                                                                                                   
  → ∃[ (S₁ × S₂) ∈ (Type & Type) ] ((S ≡ (S₁ => S₂)) & (T₁ <: S₁) & (S₂ <: T₂))                                                                                     
lemma-inversion₁ (s-refl {T₁ => T₂}) = (T₁ × T₂) , (refl × s-refl × s-refl)                                                                                         
lemma-inversion₁ (s-arrow {S₁} {S₂} T₁<:S₁ S₂<∶T₂) = (S₁ × S₂) , (refl × T₁<:S₁ × S₂<∶T₂)                                                                           
lemma-inversion₁ (s-trans {S} S<:U U<:T₁=>T₂) with lemma-inversion₁ U<:T₁=>T₂                                                                                       
... | (U₁ × U₂) , (U≡U₁=>U₂ × T₁<:U₁ × U₂<:T₂) with lemma-inversion₁ (subst (S <:_) U≡U₁=>U₂ S<:U)                                                                  
... | (S₁ × S₂) , (S≡S₁=>S₂ × U₂<:S₁ × S₂<:U₂) = (S₁ × S₂) , (S≡S₁=>S₂ × s-trans T₁<:U₁ U₂<:S₁ × s-trans S₂<:U₂ U₂<:T₂)
```

This looks correct to me, but I get:

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:                                                                                                            
  lemma-inversion₁                                                                                                                                                  
Problematic calls:                                                                                                                                                  
  lemma-inversion₁ (s-trans S<:U U<:T₁=>T₂)                                                                                                                         
  | lemma-inversion₁ U<:T₁=>T₂                                                                                                                                      
  lemma-inversion₁ U<:T₁=>T₂
  lemma-inversion₁ (subst (_<:_ S) U≡U₁=>U₂ S<:U)
```

Looks like Agda can't infer termination because of the `subst`?  Is that right?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to pattern-match on `refl`, like this:

```
... | (U₁ × U₂) , (refl × T₁<:U₁ × U₂<:T₂) with lemma-inversion₁ S<:U
```

This lets Agda infer that `U = U₁ => U₂` and the termination checker is happy.